# Why doesn't Neovim highlight the entire syntax?

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

Neovim does not highlight functions and methods.

In Neovim:

[image: Neovim]

In Vscode:

[image: Vscode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Neovim uses syntax highlighting based on regular expressions. The default syntax file for Python does not include rules to highlight methods and functions.

If you want to add such functionality, you have a few options:

1. Extend the built-in syntax highlight for Python. You can add new syntax rules in your configuration file (see [:he syntax](https://neovim.io/doc/user/syntax.html) for more information) or use one of the plugins that implements this. For example, [vim-python/python-syntax](https://github.com/vim-python/python-syntax) do what you want.
2. Use a [treesitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter)-based  highlighting. You need to install the [treesitter plugin](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) using your favorite package manager and execute `:TSInstall python` to download and compile the treesitter parser for Python. The treesitter highlights functions and methods by default:
   [image]
3. Another option is to use LSP semantic syntax highlighting. I'm not sure if there are any LSP servers for Python which supports this feature, but there is a [plugin](https://github.com/jackguo380/vim-lsp-cxx-highlight) that implements that for C++. Therefore, you can also consider this option if you encounter a similar problem in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installed the Semshi plugin. It is really great. The syntax highlighting is very cool and works out of the box. It also provides built-in highlighting when you are over a word. I can highly recommend it.

https://github.com/numirias/semshi